# how can i add am/pm in time combobox

Tags: php, combobox

I have the time combobox with 30 minutes increment but I am unable to add am/pm in that.

This is the current time format showing `(12:00, 12:30, 01:00, 01:30)`.
I want to display time like `(12:00pm, 12:30pm, 01:00am, 01:30am)`.

**My code is below:**

```
for($hours=0; $hours<24; $hours++) // the interval for hours is '1'
    for($mins=0; $mins<60; $mins+=15) // the interval for mins is '30'
echo '<option value="'.str_pad($hours,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT).':'.str_pad($mins,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT).'">'.str_pad($hours,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT).':'.str_pad($mins,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT).'</option>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following inside your second `for`

```
$ampm = ($hours >= 12) ? 'pm' : 'am';
```

then concat the `$ampm` to your string.

This won't give you 1:00pm, though, it will give you 13:00 pm based on your current code, so you'll also need to address that